# Is it possible to use the `master^{tree}` syntax of `git cat-file -p` to print blobs?

Tags: git

By reading a blog post, I became familar with the `master^{tree}` syntax in `git cat-file -p master^{tree}` used to print the tree object corresponding to the `master` branch (commit).

Can I use this syntax to also print the blobs in this tree? I've tried with the following commands, which don't work:

`git cat-file -p master^{blob}` and `git cat-file -p master^{tree}^{blob}`

In what Git `man` page can I read more about the `master^{tree}` syntax? It's not described in `git cat-file --help`.

```
nlykkei:~/projects/demos/git-test (change-config)$ git cat-file -p master^{tree}
100644 blob 980a0d5f19a64b4b30a87d4206aade58726b60e3    hello-world
100644 blob 6bbf1b1052278a9507b22f1cac84503a05eb935c    package.json
100644 blob e82dbc14b98ed7d67e88381d58732b00459c180f    random-file
100644 blob b07036b6d12da665c096d9fe3b4d8e3551147e31    some-file
nlykkei:~/projects/demos/git-test (change-config)$ git cat-file -p master^{blob}
error: master^{blob}: expected blob type, but the object dereferences to tree type
fatal: Not a valid object name master^{blob}
nlykkei:~/projects/demos/git-test (change-config)$ git cat-file -p master^{tree}^{blob}
error: master^{tree}^{blob}: expected blob type, but the object dereferences to tree type
fatal: Not a valid object name master^{tree}^{blob}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> By reading a blog post, I became familiar with the `master^{tree}` syntax in `git cat-file -p master^{tree}` used to print the tree object corresponding to the `master` branch (commit).

Technically, this has little to do with `git cat-file` itself.

The suffix `^{type}`, where *`type`* is any of four Git's object types—`tag`, `commit`, `tree`, or `blob`—is actually a directive to the revision parser.  These directives are described in [the gitrevisions documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions).

The revision parser itself can be invoked separately using `git rev-parse`:

```
git rev-parse master^{tree}
```

for instance.  Here's the result in a clone of the Git repository for Git:

```
$ git rev-parse master
d61d20c9b413225793f8a0b491bbbec61c184e26
$ git rev-parse master^{tree}
a09123ee85e55b1de2e3c70c43588f10d885cacb
```

which shows how `master^{tree}` refers to a different hash ID than does `master`.  Using `git cat-file -t`, we can see why that's the case:

```
$ git cat-file -t master
commit
$ git cat-file -t master^{tree}
tree
```

Object `d61d20c9b413225793f8a0b491bbbec61c184e26` *is* a commit object, and object `a09123ee85e55b1de2e3c70c43588f10d885cacb` *is* a tree object.  So when we ask `git cat-file` to print that object's *content* (with `-p`), we get either the commit content, or the tree content.

> Can I use this syntax to also print the blobs in this tree?

No.

A commit object itself contains data like this:

```
$ git cat-file -p master | sed 's/@/ /'
tree a09123ee85e55b1de2e3c70c43588f10d885cacb
parent d2ea03ddeeeab6f703290af30ba89d5606858673
author Junio C Hamano <gitster pobox.com> 1588202142 -0700
committer Junio C Hamano <gitster pobox.com> 1588202142 -0700

The fifth batch

Signed-off-by: Junio C Hamano <gitster pobox.com>
```

There are a few important background items to know here:

- Every commit object is constrained to contain exactly one tree object.  That tree represents the commit's snapshot.
- Every branch name is constrained to resolve to the hash ID of an existing commit.

So if `master` resolves to commit hash *H*, we can always find one and only one tree hash *T* this way as well.  Git therefore allows `master^{tree}` which tells Git: *find the object identified by the name, then do whatever is required to find a tree object from that object*.  This always works because the name is a branch name, which resolves to a commit, which contains exactly one tree.

Trees, however, usually contain many sub-trees and/or many blobs.  In your case, the tree you showed contains four entries:

```
100644 blob 980a0d5f19a64b4b30a87d4206aade58726b60e3    hello-world
100644 blob 6bbf1b1052278a9507b22f1cac84503a05eb935c    package.json
100644 blob e82dbc14b98ed7d67e88381d58732b00459c180f    random-file
100644 blob b07036b6d12da665c096d9fe3b4d8e3551147e31    some-file
```

To resolve a tree to a specific entry *within* that tree, we must present the revision parser with a *name*.

In my case, the tree associated with the branch name `master`, after resolving from commit object to tree object, contains hundreds of names (`wc -l` reports 459 names).  Here are the last ten:

```
$ git cat-file -p master^{tree} | tail
100644 blob 95851b85b6b7181130f0cd441c2bd7ac0bfb89da    wrap-for-bin.sh
100644 blob 3a1c0e052677dca8d1bc19121d609e0c226e88ee    wrapper.c
100644 blob eab8c8d0b9aab55c8435b9f451efd81e715131f8    write-or-die.c
100644 blob 6e69877f25791632d98bf7b109a2eaebd04c96af    ws.c
100644 blob 98dfa6f73f9d7cd41867f97fdae41bd4dc5ec2a1    wt-status.c
100644 blob 73ab5d4da1c0b4766cb63501b9db06c0a7fea934    wt-status.h
100644 blob 4d20069302b25a133869380bd685e921ddc0bacc    xdiff-interface.c
100644 blob 93df26900c2bfa923f1e871924ef319a6786fa72    xdiff-interface.h
040000 tree 82fc725b3f0affab0f034a80baaf9e589b870942    xdiff
100644 blob d594cba3fc9d82d94b9277e886f2bee265e552f6    zlib.c
```

To resolve from `master` to tree to, say, the blob this tree has for `zlib.c`, we must include the literal string `zlib.c`:

```
$ git rev-parse master:zlib.c
d594cba3fc9d82d94b9277e886f2bee265e552f6
```

This is the case even with a tree object that contains only one entry; `hash^{blob}` is only permitted if *`hash`* already resolves to a blob object.

This same syntax works with most Git commands, including `git cat-file`:

```
$ git cat-file -t master:zlib.c
blob
```

Read through the gitrevisions documentation carefully.  There is a huge amount of information here, represented in relatively few words.

Comment: Do you know why `man gitrevisions` says: *A revision parameter `<rev>` typically, but not necessarily, names a commit object. It uses what is called an extended SHA-1 syntax.*, when the man page shows various formats for a revision parameter, not only SHA-1?

Comment: The first part ("typically ... names a commit object") means that most users mostly are trying to name a commit. That's true for `git show`, `git log`, `git diff`, and so on, all of which use gitrevisions syntax. The second part ("uses ... an extended ... syntax") tells you that while SHA-1 values are allowed, more things than SHA-1 values *work*.